# Android how to serialize data and write to a text file

Tags: java, android

I have a ArrayList of my customized type. If i convert to String and write to a file and my other code reads the file as a String I dont know how to convert the read String back to my customized type.

I am planning to serialize this custom ArrayList and write to a file. Later for reading, deserialize it and read it as my custom ArrayList.

How do I achieve this? Any code would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` classes for this. See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/) tutorial.